# Accessibility in Docker volumes

Tags: docker, docker-volume, azure-aks

I'm reading a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/intro-to-docker-containers/4-how-docker-containers-work#what-is-a-volume) from Microsoft that states about Docker volumes

> **Volumes are stored within directories on the host filesystem**. Docker
> will mount and manage the volumes in the container. Once mounted,
> **these volumes are isolated from the host machine**.
>
> Multiple containers can simultaneously use the same volumes. Volumes
> also don't get removed automatically when a container stops using the
> volume.
>
> In our example, we can create a directory on our container host and
> mount this volume into the container when we create the tracking
> portal container. When our tracking portal logs data, **we can access
> this information via the container host's filesystem**. We'll have
> access to this log file even if our container is removed.

I'm confused as I understand that the volumes are isolated from the host machine, but how can that be if we can access to the data via the host.

Comment: It's all namespaces. Someone with root on the host can get into any namespace they want (see `nsenter`).

Comment: Mind, on non-Linux platforms you traditionally have a virtualized Linux kernel, and _that_ is what has access to all the namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm less familiar with Docker on Windows, but I'm sure it's probably the same as Linux in this regard...

Docker volumes are "isolated on the host machine" by being in a particular location with particular permissions on the host's filesystem (i.e. via namespaces).  Users/accounts with elevated permissions would still be granted access to those directories/files.

By contrast a bind mount can be made to (pretty much) any directory on the host's file system.

Comment: So you are saying that that a regular user cannot access the particular location where the volume is created by Docker?